# overlappings when texgyrepagella is used with stmaryrd

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, ieeetran, scaling

Consider running xelatex or lualatex on the following code:

```
\documentclass[compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Extension=.otf]{texgyrepagella-math}
%\usepackage{mleftright} % no better with\mleft and \mright
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
\(\left\lBrack\check f\right\rBrack\)
\(\left\llbracket\check f\right\rrbracket\)
\end{document}
```

There are two problems:

1. In the first occurence there is too much space below f: the brackets scale a bit too much.
2. In the second occurence the caron over f overlaps with the right double bracket.

Is there a better way to typeset ⟦f̌ ⟧ ? We need (xe/lua)-latex, Tex Gyre Pagella, and [10pt,journal,compsoc]IEEEtran (which was shortened above).

I wish the solution to be automatic, i.e., by a macro, say, \addDoubleBrackets{x} which adds brackets around x and takes care of scaling and spacing depending on x automatically.

[image: output of xelatex on the above]

Comment: No `\left` and `\right`; this is a case where `\,` comes in handy: `\(\lBrack\,\check{f}\,\rBrack\)`

Answer (score 1):

Granted that the positioning of the accent is suboptimal, you can add `\,` in a couple of places:

```
\documentclass[compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Extension=.otf]{texgyrepagella-math}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\(\lBrack\,\check{f}\,\rBrack\)
\(\lBrack\,\check{f}\rBrack\)

\(\bigl\lBrack\,\check{f}\,\bigr\rBrack\)
\(\bigl\lBrack\,\check{f}\bigr\rBrack\)

\(\llbracket\,\check{f}\,\rrbracket\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't find it necessary to increase the size of the brackets, particularly if other symbols are bracketed in the same line.

Comment: Thanks. This is all very true. I should have probably mentioned it earlier that I want the solution to be automatic. In the original code, the bracketing is done by the macro, which ideally should do all the scaling and adding horizontal spaces itself (but does not do it currently). The macro is used, grossly simplifying, as \adddoublebrackets{x}, where x is some portion of math code, to give some examples, "c|_z", "c'\smalltriangleleft f". Problem statement adapted.

Comment: @PetrosTravioli Sorry, but quality typesetting requires some manual intervention. The shape of ‘f’ is good for many cases, in some other case it needs care.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `libertinusmath-regular` which is similiar to Pagella

```
\documentclass[compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Extension=.otf]{libertinusmath-regular}
\begin{document}
    \(\left\lBrack\check f\right\rBrack\)
    \(\left\llbracket\check f\right\rrbracket\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is libertinus similar to Palatino/Palladio?

Comment: Btw. the left f overlaps slightly with the left bracket. It is not that bad, though.

Comment: libertinus has another problem: the small parentheses in $ a_{\left(\right)} $ are not displayed properly. You might argue that left and right should not occur here. But they do occur if this construction is not typed directly, but is a result of compositions of macros, one of them putting the argument as a subscript, and the other one providing the scalable parentheses in the argument.